# Why is the accusative pronoun 'ci' the only one that doesn't descend from Latin?

Tags: etymology

[Wiktionary claims](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ci#Italian)  that the etymology of the accusative first person plural pronoun  *ci* is < L. *ecce hic* "look at this here".

This is uncommon in the Romance languages, which have largely retained reflexes of L. *nos*.

Granted that sometimes things happen in language change without an obvious cause, was there any reason in Italian why this pronoun alone did not descend analogically like *vi* < L. *vos* did? (I know *loro* did not either, but it does descend from L. *illorum* so it's still not a novel form unlike *ci*.)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @jogloran!

Comment: Thanks :) I've wanted an Italian SE for some time, basically ever since [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/italian-past-participle-ending-uto). In fact, see my comment: *"Hopefully we can get Italian.SE started at some point... – jogloran May 10 '12 at 14:06"*

Comment: Great question! Don't take Wiktionary as gospel truth, though. Actual dictionaries' opinions differ: [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/) gives as its etymology simply *hīce*, the late Latin form for *hīc*, “here”, Zanichelli gives the same (in the form *hīcce*), while [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ci) concurs with Wiktionary.

Comment: My unsourced, intuitive guess is that the loss of most final consonants from Latin to Italian led to *nos* being easily mistaken for *non* (“not”), and so it would have been substituted in the use with something else. Something similar has certainly happened in other cases: for instance, the loss of the distinction between long and short vowels led to abandon *ōs* for “mouth” (in favour of *bucca* > *bocca*, and still surviving in derived words such as *orale*, “oral”) because it became too similar to *ŏs* (> *osso*), “bone”.

Comment: DaG: Yes, that occurred to me as a possibility too. But supposing that *nos* developed analogously to *vos*, shouldn't the form be **ni* in analogy to *vi*, which should be distinctive enough from *non*? Of course, the word could have proceeded through a phase like **noi*, but evidently that word's similarity to *non* wasn't a problem...

Comment: Note that the same phenomenon hasn't happened in other Romance languages, despite the same similarity (French: *nous/non*, Castilian Spanish: *nos/no*, Romanian: *ne/nu*).

Comment: And note also that the dual meaning of *ci* can create confusion, too: *Io e Maria non ci vediamo più da quando c'è stato quell'incidente* -- does it mean that we are both blind?

Comment: Just as an info, in Sicilian _ci_ is also the dative 3rd person singular pronoun (_gli_ and _le_ in Italian)

Answer (score 5):

Nice and controversial question. Quite certainly VI doesn't come from VOS but from the adverb IBI. No doubts that in early Tuscan, the *pronome atono* VO derives from VOS (Guittone d'Arezzo "...gente che *vo* vede" people see *you*) but is soon replaced by *vi*. The source is the *bible* of the history of Italian grammar: Gerhard Rohlfs "Grammatica storica della lingua italiana" -  Einaudi, Vol 2 pag. 161:

(...) Nella lingua letteraria questa *vo* venne presto sostituito da *vi* (*ve*). Che questa forma provenga dal più antico *vo* per indebolimento (Parodi, R I8, 619) è poco probabile. Questo *vi* sarà piuttosto da identificare coll'avverbio di luogo *vi ( < ibi)*. *Vi scrivo* significava dunque originariamente '*io scrivo costì*. Questa forma s'è estesa in tutt'ltalia, cfr. già nell'antico milanese *ve digo* (Uguccione,96), *ve stoverà sofrir* (97), antico veneto *ve domando* (Monad, I46), *ve voio dire* (377), antico napoletano *ve scrivo* (553) (...)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that as an adverb of place *qui* (here) making a parallel to *vi* as abbreviated from *ivi* (lat. *ibi* = there),  one was referring to where the person that was talking was, while the other referred to a location **other than** where the person was. As such they could be a sliding from abverb of place to clitic personal pronoun as *us* intended as "people here" and *them* intended as "people there"

Comment: Is there evidence that the second person plural clitic pronoun *vi* is < *ivi* and not derived instead from L. *vos*?

Comment: No, I was merely trying to make an hypothesis that could explain it as a sliding from the adverb of place, it would make sense if related to _vi_ as also deriving from the adverb of place. I thought that the answer was clear in my intent, I edited it to make that a bit more clear. The usage of ci and vi as location of the person talking and every other location is from an etymological dictionary instead

Comment: Below, the evidence. Ciao.